# How to write the wedge product in terms of Levi-Civita symbol

Tags: exterior-algebra

Suppose we have a one form $E_i$ and a two form $\omega_{jk}$.The wedge product between these forms is $$E_i\wedge \omega_{jk}=E_i \omega_{jk}-E_j \omega_{ik}+E_k \omega_{ij}$$

Is there a way to write this formula in a compact notation using the Levi-Civita symbol $\epsilon_{ijk}$ ?

Comment: Do you have a specific dimension for your space in mind? If $n=3$, then the expression is quite simple. Not so much in other dimensions.

Comment: yes we are in 3 dimensional space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $(E\wedge \omega)_{ijk}=3E_{[i}\omega_{jk]}$, where the [square brackets indicate antisymmetrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_tensor#Antisymmetric_and_symmetric_tensors).

Also remember that you can express the [generalized Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Definitions_of_the_generalized_Kronecker_delta) using the Levi-Civita symbols as
$$\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon^{lmn}=\delta_{ijk}^{lmn}.$$
This generalized delta is the antisymmetrization tensor, because it satisfies
$$\delta_{ijk}^{lmn}A_{lmn}=3!A_{[ijk]}.$$

Using this, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
(E\wedge \omega)_{ijk}
&=3E_{[i}\omega_{jk]} \\
&=\frac{3}{3!}\delta^{lmn}_{ijk}E_{l}\omega_{mn} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon^{lmn}E_{l}\omega_{mn}.
\end{aligned}$$
I hope it helps.